# jQuery $.get doesn't put out any data

Tags: jquery

what I'm trying to do is simply catch some data from a file and insert to another file's (the one that that the js is in) div. It won't work and I can't seem to find the failure in here. I googled for it, but it gave me no answers. Any suggestions?

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("li#twitter-widget a").click(function(event){

        $('<span class="loading">Lade Inhalte</span>').appendTo("div#news-widget");

        $.get("widgets/twitter.widget", function(data){
            $(data).find("div.twtr-doc").appendTo("div#news-widget");
            alert( data );
            $('span.loading').remove();
        });

    });

});
```

**The twitter.widget**

http://nopaste.info/1a6c866a15.html

**The HTML that I want the data to be inserted to**

http://nopaste.info/435800b8f8.html

**The Problem**

alert(data) doesn't put out anything.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: alert(data) doesn't put out anything? OR alert doesn't show at all?

Comment: - newest jQuery version from google, alert window opens, now errors thrown

Comment: have you tried using a tool like Firebug to see exactly what the HTTP request and response look like? You may find it's a lot more helpful than your `alert()` call.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery injects scripts retrieved via AJAX into the DOM and removes them from the "data". Since your "twitter.widget" is nothing more than two script elements, your "data" is going to be empty.

You might want to use [$.getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) instead.

Comment: doesn't work out.. I just want the <script> stuff in an external file - is there any possibility to still load the twitter stream?

Answer (score 0):

You're making an ajax call to an html page? Is that page statgic or a re you trying to access one of the services in that page? Have you looked into using load instead? That will get you sections of an html I believe, wich can then be assigned to a var and appended.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I'm attempting to load the result of a <script>-section (the output is a twitter activity stream div) and append the div to my document.